# Run CSSTransition inside TransitionGroup when any value changes

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group

I'm looking at the [TransitionGroup documentation example](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group), and I'm trying to update it to run the CSSTransition whenever the `text` value is updated for an *existing* item.

I have set up a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-kilby-ezjy03) to show my current attempt.

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { id: 1, text: 'Hello world!' },
    { id: 2, text: 'How are you?' },
]);

return (
    <Container style={{ marginTop: '2rem' }}>
        <ListGroup style={{ marginBottom: '1rem' }}>
            <TransitionGroup className="todo-list">
                {items.map(({ id, text }) => (
                    <CSSTransition
                        key={id}
                        timeout={500}
                        classNames="item">
                        <ListGroup.Item>{text}</ListGroup.Item>
                    </CSSTransition>
                ))}
            </TransitionGroup>
        </ListGroup>

        <Button
            onClick={() => {
                setItems((items) => [
                    { id: 1, text: 'Hello to you!' },
                    { id: 2, text: 'How do you do?' },
                ]);
            }}>
        Update Items
        </Button>
    </Container>
```

);

When I click the button, the text content updates without the CSSTransition. I know this is because of the `id` not changing, and this is what `key` is set to, but how do I have TransitionGroup take into account the `text` value?

How do I keep the same `id` but update the text value with a transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since key={id}, the key won't change when the text is updated, and **the CSSTransition won't trigger because it doesn't get rerendered**.

We can change the `key` to include the `id` and the `text`, so the component will always get rerendered when the text changes. We also want to add `exit={false}` to prevent us from seeing extra components while the new components are transitioning in. Here's what that should look like:

```
<CSSTransition
  key={`${id}${text}`}
  timeout={500}
  classNames="item"
  exit={false}
>
```

Here's a codesandbox example of [this solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-dream-cl9hyo?file=/index.js).